# Change BorderColor of clicked item (itemrenderer) in List

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, itemrenderer

Hello I want to set the BorderColor of certain Item Renderers (textInput) of a List. By default all have a common border color, but I want for example when clicking in an item to have a red border.

I tried this on a click event in my itemRenderer,

```
mytextInput.setStyle("color", 0xDDDDDD);
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any help.

Thx

Comment: The style property, `color` denotes the color of the text, you should use `borderColor` instead, or is it a typo in your sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you're extending Spark `TextInput` control all the problems of that kind should be solved using skins. Create custom skin with the border you like.